# Server module that returns a bearer token to use client side to GET from API. Get: Cannot import $lib/server/name.ts into client-side code

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I have a function that POSTs to the authentication server, and passes along the response using return data. This is in $lib/server because it has API keys in it.

Then I call the function from $lib/aT.ts. All it contains is this:

```
import { fetchAccessToken } from '$lib/server/fetchaccesstoken'

export const aT = (async () => {
    const accessToken = await fetchAccessToken();
    return accessToken;
  })();
```

Then in +layout.svelte say, I import it with `import { aT } from '$lib/aT';`.

Doing so gives the error. I understand why, because down the chain it's importing from a /server module and so needs to be kept secret and safe.

What I would like help with is exporting just a variable from aT.ts, but making +layout.svelte etc. wait for the variable to be available, as otherwise their fetch requests to the API will just be rejected.

I've tried many ways, including just copy pasting all the info into each +page.server.js and +layout.server.js but it was obviously mucky and hard to maintain. Importing aT and calling it with await has worked but only in the server only modules. The bearer token has an expiry of 60 mins and is also scoped to only read so not too worried if it's seen.

Alternately, I can leave it all server side and pass the data from +layout.server.js to +layout.svelte, but I can't find any info on this at all.

Thank you.